# Is it possible to have a datepicker without Jquery UI?

Tags: python, django

I have a form(Django Forms) which has multiple date fields. I did use Jquery UI initially, but want to keep bulky packages out. And indeed wanted to have a simple light datepicker. Is it possible internally with Django forms??

Comment: what did you try about datepicker in your config ? It's more easy for helping you

Comment: Sure its possible, By default django's `DateField` uses a `DateInput` widget, but you can change that to use your own custom widget with your desired functionality... When you've done all that though you'll probably realise that there are much better supported javascript implementations available.

Comment: Thank you. Internally using DateInput barely does not show a calendar UI is it??

Comment: I didn't say anything about a calendar, the default one lets you pick a date by entering it in a text input field. Either way your question is too broad/off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.forms import SelectDateWidget

date = forms.DateField(widget = SelectDateWidget(), label="Date")
```

Gives you a built in date picker.